# How to extract every Monday and every fortnightly Monday from a range of two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, algorithm, datepicker, date-range

I'm using the infamous jQuery UI's Datepicker, and in my form I select a range of two dates.

First represents the **starting** date and the other represents the **end** date.

What I need now is the algorthm, some tips and directions or helpers for calculating every Monday between these two dates.

For instance:

```
start: 2011-06-01
end:   2011-06-30
```

Should extract me these 4 (four) dates witch lay on Mondays:

```
1st: 2011-06-06
2nd: 2011-06-13
3rd: 2011-06-20
4th: 2011-06-27
```

How could I achive this?

And also, I'd need it for every fortnightly Monday:

Result for fortnightly should be:

```
1st: 2011-06-06
2rd: 2011-06-20
```

Comment: Do you want a php solution (>> title of your post) or a javascript solution (>> tags of your post) ?

Comment: PHP would be more accepted, but JS is fine as well :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$start = strtotime('2011-06-01');
$end = strtotime('2011-06-30');

$mondays=array();

while( $start <= $end  ) {
  if ( date('N',$start)==1 )   
    $mondays[]=$start;

  $start += 86400; //> incrementing one day   
                   //> i could have used strtotime('+1 day') but math sum is 10x faster

}
//> Untested
```

Now you have all your mondays in `$mondays` array.

### Addendum

Be aware that `+86400` could lead to inconsistent result due to daylight saving. If your app is mission-critical better use `+1 day`

`strtotime('2010-10-31') + 86400` returns `2010-10-31`

Comment: thank you alot my Yes friend! this is the solution I was looking for ;) I'll buy you a beer one day ;)

Comment: I'm plussing you as much as Stack Overflow allows me my friend Yes friend! :)

Comment: @metaforce: i have added a bit of a warning in my reply. take care of that

Answer (score 3):

```
function getAllMondays($from_date, $to_date){
// getting number of days between two date range.
$number_of_days = count_days(strtotime($from_date),strtotime($to_date));

for($i = 1; $i<=$number_of_days; $i++){
    $day = Date('l',mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')+$i,date('y')));
    if($day == 'Monday'){
        echo Date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')+$i,date('y'))),'<br/>';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: count_days is an useless overhead you are adding there

Comment: đesi srbine, krava te ubola :D

Comment: @yes123 I know, this is just a school example I'm giving to him. Later customization is required :)

Comment: you cannot customize such example with count_days. the script provided only works with count_days