# Extracting dates from date range

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

Part of my answer was answered by dynamic: 
[How to extract every Monday and every fortnightly Monday from a range of two dates in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518094/how-to-extract-every-monday-and-every-fortnightly-monday-from-a-range-of-two-dat)

I've added a foreach loop to print all the mondays in this example:

```
$start = strtotime('2016-09-05');
$end = strtotime('2016-09-30');

$mondays=array(); 
$tuesdays=array();  

while( $start <= $end  ) {

if ( date('N',$start)==1 )   
$mondays[]=$start;
$start += 86400;  

}  
foreach ($mondays as $item) {  
print date("D. Y-m-d", ($item)); 
print ("<br>");
}
```

and i get these results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIvmi.jpg)

But how do i add an else/if statements to display the tuesdays for example

if the date begins with  $start = strtotime('2016-09-06');

I want it to show:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trs8s.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Ummm... *"add a day?"*

Comment: If you want loop  the same days of week as the 1 day `$start = strtotime('+1 week', $start); `

Comment: @splash58 I believe they want to add a day, not a week. This is what I take from seeing their screenshots.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see there Mon, Mon, Mon... Tue, Tue, Tue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, we first find the DayOfWeek, and then find all dof in range:

```
// Data

$StartDate = strtotime('2016-09-06');
$EndDate   = strtotime('2016-09-30');

$DayOfWeek = date("l", $StartDate); // Determine day of week

$LoopDate = $StartDate;

// Find all DayOfWeek's Between Start and End

$Result = [$StartDate];

while (true) {
    $NextDayOfWeek = strtotime("next " . $DayOfWeek, $LoopDate);

    if ($NextDayOfWeek > $EndDate) {
        break;
    }

    $Result[] = $LoopDate = $NextDayOfWeek;
}

// Print Result

/**
 | 2016-09-06
 | 2016-09-13
 | 2016-09-20
 | 2016-09-27
 */
foreach( $Result as $Row ) {
    echo date("Y-m-d", $Row) . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, enjoy

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with your current approach:

```
$start = strtotime('2016-09-05');
$end = strtotime('2016-09-30');

while($start <= $end) {
    if(date("D", $start) == "Mon"){
        $mondays[] = $start;
    }
    elseif(date("D", $start) == "Tue"){
        $tuesdays[] = $start;
    }
    $start += 86400;
}

foreach ($mondays as $item){
    echo date("D. Y-m-d", $item);
    echo "<br>";
}

echo "<br>";

foreach ($tuesdays as $item){
    echo date("D. Y-m-d", $item);
    echo "<br>";
}
```